# Is it possible to group together strings and count group members in an ordered Java list using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an ordered list of Strings, let's say `"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa"`. I would like to group adjacent equal strings together and count them, so the result of the operation should be a `List` looking like this: `{"aaa":3}, {"bbb":2}, {"aaa", 1}`. Note that the task is not to just group by the same values and count them (otherwise I could simply use `groupingBy` with `counting`), but group by only adjacent strings with the same value, and if the same string appears later in the list then it should be considered as separate. Basically, I need this piece of code to create a table header with appropriate colspans out of an existing data structure.

I'd like to know if there's a reasonably good way to achieve this task using Java 8 streams. I know how to do it using an old-school loop, just thought maybe streams provide a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom collector as far as I can see, but it does not differ much then a loop (same logic would be applied). Also notice that I've used `SimpleEntry` instead of a `Pair` to hold each element from the List.

```
private static Collector<String, ?, List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>>> adiacentCollector() {

    class Acc {

        private String previous;

        private List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        void accumulate(String elem) {
            if (previous == null) {
                previous = elem;
                result.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>(elem, 1));
                return;
            }

            if (previous.equals(elem)) {
                SimpleEntry<String, Integer> current = result.get(result.size() - 1);
                current.setValue(current.getValue() + 1);
                previous = elem;
            } else {
                SimpleEntry<String, Integer> oneMore = new SimpleEntry<String, Integer>(elem, 1);
                result.add(oneMore);
                previous = elem;
            }
        }

        Acc combine(Acc other) {

            SimpleEntry<String, Integer> lastEntry = result.get(result.size() - 1);
            SimpleEntry<String, Integer> firstEntry = other.result.get(0);

            if (lastEntry.getKey().equals(firstEntry.getKey())) {
                lastEntry.setValue(lastEntry.getValue() + firstEntry.getValue());
                other.result.remove(0);
            }

            result.addAll(other.result);

            return this;

        }

        List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>> finisher() {
            return result;
        }

    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::accumulate, Acc::combine, Acc::finisher);
}
```

And use it:

```
 System.out.println(Stream.of("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa")
            .collect(adiacentCollector()));
```

Comment: I added the combiner so that parallel processing would be possible too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution by the `collapse` API provided [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
List<Map<String, Long>> res = StreamEx.of("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa")
        .collapse(Objects::equals, 
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .toList();

System.out.println(res); // output: [{aaa=3}, {bbb=2}, {aaa=1}]
```

Or even simpler with 'runLength':

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> res2 = StreamEx.of("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa")
                                             .runLengths().toList();

System.out.println(res2); // output: [{aaa=3}, {bbb=2}, {aaa=1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

StreamEx is the best solution. 
But here another one using a closure and reducing the stream:

The closure:

```
public class StatefulList {
    private List<Pair<String, Integer>> pairList;
    private int index = 0;

    public StatefulList() {
        this.pairList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public StatefulList add(String value) {
        if (pairList.size()==0) {
            pairList.add(new Pair<>(value, 1));
            return this;
        }
        Pair<String, Integer> last = pairList.get(index);
        if(last.getKey().equals(value)){
            pairList.set(index, new Pair<>(last.getKey(), last.getValue() + 1));
        } else {
            pairList.add(++index, new Pair<>(value, 1));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return pairList.toString();
    }
}
```

Reducing it:

```
Stream.of("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "aaa")
      .reduce(new StatefulList(), StatefulList::add, (a,b) -> a);
```